# Update Android calendar events

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm trying to update calendar events programmatically but I have some issues.

I'm using updating code from Google Android Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#update-event

So here's my code :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Uri updateUri = null;
        // New end for event
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
        int rows = c.getContentResolver().update(updateUri, values, null, null);
        Log.i("DEBUG_TAG", "Rows updated: " + rows);
```

But rows variable always returns 0 except when I go into apps settings, remove calendar storage, add a new calendar and a new event and then when I try to update it, it works only once. If I try to add another event and update it afterward, rows return 0 again.

Any idea?

Thanks

Please note that my app is min API level 17 (on which it doesn't work) but I tried on API level 25 and it works, so do you have any idea how to add support to my code for previous Android versions? I've also found that after some tests, it works from API level 21. Under, it doesn't.

EDIT : 
I've found a solution, check my answer below.

Comment: Why I can't add "Hello" at the beginning of my post ? When I add it, it's automatically deleted. This is funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me :

The eventID that I used was the result of the query with column `CalendarContract.Events._ID` but I had to used the ID provided by `CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID`.
Indeed if I create a new event (the first one) it has _id = 1 and event_id = 1, and if I delete it from Android Calendar App and I create a new one with my app, it has also _id = 1 but event_id = 2.
So the update query failed if I use _id instead of event_id with `withAppendedID()`.

Here's the code that worked for me. `startMillis` and `endMillis` are respectively your meeting start time and end time in milliseconds.

```
        Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI
                .buildUpon();
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, startMillis);
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, endMillis);
        Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();

        String[] column = {CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE};
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = c.getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, column, CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID+"="+Constant.ID_CALENDAR, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,cursor.getLong(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        c.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the complete fixed code in your answer (keep the explanation, though).

Comment: @deLock You're right. I've edited my post with a working code.

Comment: Great -- voting up ;)